# How to import data from opened, encrypted 2010 MS Access database to Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access

Trying to add a data source to MS Excel from 2010 password protected Access database by going to Excel-->Data-->From Access (in Get external data)-->select database.

If I remove the password from the database, I am able to add the data source/query whether or not I have the database open in Access. If I add a password and close the database, I can add the data source/query from Excel. However, if I encrypt the Access DB and open the DB, Excel fails to connect to the database and I can't query.

I set the database password using "legacy encryption method" (as mentioned on other questions pertaining to this problem), but it looks to be a database locking issue. In excel, I set the "open mode" to DB_MODE_READ but no connection is added.

Some error messages I've received while testing:

"You attempted to open a database that is already opened by user 'Admin' on machine..."  Not sure what this means - all I want is read access to the database.

"The workgroup information file is missing or opened exclusively by another user." I have looked everywhere, but can't find any information about the workgroup information file - I thought later versions of Access did away with .mdw files.

Regardless, it seems like you can't connect to or query an already-opened, encrypted 2010 Access database (unlike a non-encrypted 2010 Access database or encrypted but closed Access database). If anyone has any input on solving the issue of querying an opened, encrypted 2010 Access database, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Need to change the connection string in data-->connections-->properties-->definition-->connection string to "Share Deny None" instead of "Share Deny Write". Example connection string below.

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="";User ID=Admin;Data Source=[YOUR SOURCE];Mode=Share Deny **None**;Extended Properties="";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False